Facets refresh issues when used with View of search indexes
I have a view of Search indexes with context filters in my Drupal (9.4) site. I am using Facets (2.0.7)
I have printed facet blocks in the View template files as below
<div class="accordion accordion-search-api accordion-flush search-section__main-menu-left__filter-menu__accordion" id="filter_accordion">
              {% set current_display_id = display_id %}
              {% if current_display_id == 'blog' %}
                {{ drupal_block('facet_block:blog_type') }}
                {{ drupal_block('facet_block:posted_date') }}
                {{ drupal_block('facet_block:product') }}
                {{ drupal_block('facet_block:service') }}
                {{ drupal_block('facet_block:solution') }}
                {{ drupal_block('facet_block:industry') }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>

Now the facet blocks behave weirdly.

The do not appear clickable and the accordion housing them does not open when the page is loaded for the first time. But when an ajax refresh happens, like clicking the pager they become active and clickable
They sometimes disappear requiring a page reload.

I feel this is because of the way
